# Buildroot linux kernel clean build

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot

I am using buildroot to build linux firmware. How can I do a clean rebuild the linux kernel only (without having to build the whole thing which take an hour)?

I tried -

```
make linux-rebuild
```

but that does not do a clean.

I have also tried

```
make linux-reconfigure && make linux-rebuild
```

but that does not work either.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the messages/errors you have after those commands.

Comment: I usually `cd` to the kernel directory, then `make ARCH=<arch> clean`, and delete the *salient* **.stamp*** files, e.g. **.stamp_build**.  Be careful to not delete all of them.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to remove all of the changes in sources of the linux kernel be in buildroot directory (cd buildroot) and do following:

```
make linux-dirclean
make linux-rebuild
```

The first command will remove output/build/linux* directory and the second one will fetch and rebuild from scratch the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , and good to know about <pkg>-dirclean. but this is I was wanting to do , I was looking for a clean rebuild behaviour.

Comment: @NiladriBose how is the clean behaviour not clean with `linux-dirclean`? What do you observe?

Comment: just a note - if download cache is enabled in BR, you'll need to delete linux.tar distro there

Answer (score -1):

I've found in the buildroot /dl folder a copy of the kernel repo is stored in there as a tar.gz file. If you do not delete that file, buildroot will not pull any kernel updates.

Answer (score -3):

after reading a lot through buildroot manual and trail and error - this is what you need to do for cleaning of linux only -

```
make clean linux
```

Comment: "make clean linux" will clean the entire build, not just Linux, so this answer is wrong.

Comment: wrong , atleast for 2016.02 for cleaning entire build i had to do - make clean all. Make clean linux rebuilds linux-custom.

Comment: Hmm, Thomas is a maintainer of BR distribution. I think he knows what he is talking about.

Comment: Ok , what is the difference between make clean linux and make clean all? or in other words what is the purpose of make clean linux or make clean <package name>

Comment: Or why on earth will make clean <package name>  clean the entire build !! lol

Comment: @NiladriBose Why `make clean linux` cleans the entire build? Because that's how `make` works:  `make clean linux` will basically run `make clean` followed by `make linux`. It's not "Hey *make*, please clean the linux package" but: "*make*, please run the `clean` target and then run the `linux` target".